# Sequelize: invalid input syntax for type interval: "undefined"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Whenever i am trying to connect the postgres through the sequelize for insertion/updation/retrieval i am getting following error. Previously it was working fine, but after `npm update` it throws the following error. I removed `node_modules` and tried to install fresh and same result. Even tried `npm cache clear --force`

```
invalid input syntax for type interval: "undefined"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/xxxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/xxxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/xxxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/xxxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

```
Node: v18.1.0
NPM: 8.8.0
Postgres: 14.2
OS: ubuntu 20-04
```

**package.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
        "apn": "^2.2.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1090.0",
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "date-and-time": "^2.0.1",
        "decimal.js": "^10.3.1",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-group-routes": "^1.1.0",
        "fcm-node": "^1.6.1",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
        "helmet": "^4.6.0",
        "ioredis": "^4.28.2",
        "joi": "^17.5.0",
        "jose": "^4.3.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "mmmagic": "^0.5.3",
        "multer": "^1.4.4",
        "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
        "pg": "^8.7.1",
        "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
        "rate-limiter-flexible": "^2.3.6",
        "sequelize": "^6.12.0-beta.3",
        "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0",
        "winston": "^3.3.3",
        "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5",
        "winston-mail": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "better-docs": "^2.3.2",
        "chai": "^4.3.6",
        "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "@faker-js/faker": "^6.1.2",
        "jsdoc": "^3.6.7",
        "mocha": "^7.1.0",
        "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
        "nyc": "^15.1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, you assinged 'undefined' for sequelize option 'timezone'.